# How to specify a destination path on a virtual machine resource in a Azure DevOps deployment using multi-stage YAML

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, continuous-deployment

I'm new to Azure DevOps so I'm trying to understand how to specify things in YAML.  I understand that Deployment Groups are not currently reachable directly with a multi-stage YAML pipeline, though I am able to automate deployment to a virtual machine in a Deployment Group using separate build and release pipelines (the second being created graphically in a GUI in a manner that doesn't permit me to see or modify the source, which makes me nervous for several reasons).

What I want to do instead is have a multi-stage YAML pipeline that deploys to that same virtual machine inside an "environment," which I understand IS possible with multi-stage YAML pipelines. What I've never yet seen documented is how to specify where on the virtual machine the deployment ends up. If I want, for example, to deploy to C:\spaghetti\meatball on my virtual machine, how would I specify that in the deploy stage of a YAML pipeline?

UPDATE:
This YAML seems to work (work secrets have been obscured, of course):

```html
# ASP.NET
# Build and test ASP.NET projects.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/aspnet/build-aspnet-4

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'



stages: 
- stage: build
  displayName: Build
  jobs:
  - job: Build

    steps:
    - checkout: self
    #without this first one, bad things happen!!
    - task: NuGetCommand@2
      inputs:
        command: 'restore'
        restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
        feedsToUse: 'config'
        nugetConfigPath: 'NuGet.config'
        
    - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1


    - task: VSBuild@1
      inputs:
        solution: '$(solution)'
        msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
        platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
        configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

    - task: VSTest@2
      inputs:
        platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
        configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
        ArtifactName: 'drop'
        publishLocation: 'Container'


- stage: Release
  displayName: Release
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['build.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'))
  jobs:

  - deployment:
    displayName: Release
    environment: 
        name: QA
        resourceType: VirtualMachine
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: CopyFiles@2
            inputs:  
              #ONLY COPIES AN UGLY .ZIP, BUT GOOD ENOUGH FOR HELLO WORLD
              SourceFolder: '$(Agent.WorkFolder)\1\drop'
              Contents: '**\*.zip'
              OverWrite: true
              #ACTUAL TARGET ON THE SERVER
              TargetFolder: 'C:\QA\XXXXX\YYYYY'
```

Answer (score 0):

Deployment groups and YAML deployment jobs targeting machines within an environment function roughly equivalently -- the artifacts are downloaded to a working location on the machine that is running the agent. Then you can copy them to the desired destination. This would just be a `step` within your pipeline.

Comment: Thanks for that. It is the copying of the artifacts to the desired destination that I've found zero examples of after numerous searches. It seems like one of the most essential things about a deployment, and yet it's cloaked in mystery.

Comment: @GusMueller There's no mystery, it's **exactly** the same process as it was in classic pipelines. You use the Copy Files task. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: I've tried the targetFolder parameter of CopyFIles@2 and it only seems to reference the agent, not the destination server. I have no idea how to get the file to the destination server, and documentation remains abysmal.

Comment: In deployment groups *and* in environments, the agent **is on** the target server. You don't have to get the files *to* the target server, they are **already there**. i.e. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/jobs-deployment-strategy-rolling?view=azure-pipelines

Comment: the target server (a virtual machine in an environment) has no d: drive, and yet my deployment log is full of lines like this:

Copying D:\a\1\a\XXXX.SourceManifest.xml to C:\QA\Web Sites\AzureDevOpsTest2\a\XXX.SourceManifest.xml

where is this??

Comment: @GusMueller Update your question to include your YAML.